# Debounce click on an AJAX link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, debouncing

Is it possible to debounce the click of a link? If a user clicks too many times too fast on a pjax link it'll break the load of new content.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-pjax]', loadNewContent);

var $target = $('main.content section.context'),
$fake = $('main.fake'),
$fakeContext = $('main.fake section.context');

function loadNewContent() {

    event.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
    url = $this.attr('href');

    $fake.addClass('is--loading');

    $.pjax({
        url: url,
        fragment: 'body',
        container: $fakeContext
    });

    $fake.one(transitionEnd, function() {
        $target.html($fake.find('section.context').html());
        $fake.removeClass('is--loading');
        $fake.off(transitionEnd);
    });

}
```

Any thoughts? I tried this, but it stopped the loadNewContent from firing. (https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce)

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[data-pjax]', $.debounce(1000, true, function() {
    loadNewContent();
}));
```

Comment: what if you set a flag to pending when triggered and set to done when response is received.

Comment: @binariedMe Yes that sounds like it could work. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ProfessorAllman Sorry I updated my debounce method...

Comment: See the generic explanation

Comment: what is this `$.debounce()` function ? did you write it or is it a plugin ? If you wrote it, please, provide the code, if not, tell us which plugin it is...

Comment: @n00dl3 sorry it is https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce will update question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work :

```
var callWaiting = false;
callAjax() {
  if(!callWaiting) {
    callWaiting = true;
    makeHttpCall(url, data, function(response) {callWaiting = false;});
    callWaiting = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried implementing this into my loadNewContent() but doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Where do you get response in your code for the call you are making?

Comment: BTW I have updated the logic. Hope that solves the issue

Comment: Ah yes. I think I understand now. Thanks!